# Prawn: PDF generation with progress bar or spinner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spinner, progress, prawn, prawnto

I'm using prawn and prawnto for PDF-generation in my rails-app. Is there a way to show the user a spinner or progress bar while the PDF is generated?? I think about showing a spinner-div in the document with the "generate-pdf-link" when starting the pdf-action and then removing it when the rendering finished (everything e.g. with jquery). How can I trigger that??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you able to setup progress bar ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating the PDF immediately, you could display a result page with a spinner, and generate the pdf in a background job. I recommend the Gems [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) for creating background jobs, placing them on multiple queues, and processing them later. There are good Railscasts for both. You can use a [jQuery Timer plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Timer) to check periodically if the PDF has been generated.